# Facebook login not working for Android app in beta

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I have an Android app that uses Facebook login. When I add the user I am testing under Roles -> Test Users, it all works. However, when I release the app to beta testing and try to use Facebook login with a user that is NOT a Test User, it fails: OAuthException, code: 200, message: Cannot call API on behalf of this user

I have included both debugging and release hashes in the Facebook developer portal under Settings -> Basic -> Android -> Key Hashes.

The app has NEVER been released before, so I think the reason Facebook login is not working maybe because FB checks if the Google Play Package Name is in the app store, and if not, it fails.

I really cannot think of any other reason.

I do not really want to release something into production that will fail, but at this point I don't know what else I can do, except to release it and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I released it, still it did not work.

This was the solution:

In FB developer console there is Settings -> Advanced, in there is a setting called "Country Restricted" - make sure this is OFF.